# Fiber signal loss - works on Cisco 4510 but not Catalyst 9300?

Tags: cisco, fiber

We are performing major switch upgrades and moving from a collapsed core design to a proper Core, Distribution, Access design. We have a very odd problem where our fiber connections going from the 4510 to an access closet (Avaya ERS 5698) that currently work fine, do not work when patched into the 9300. No link light whatsoever, and the command `sh interface te1/1/1 transceiver` says -40dB loss (basically no light signal).

We have tried multiple ports on the 9300s, new transceivers and new cables on both ends. We also had a company come in and verify our fiber runs are fine. Are newer switches more sensitive to loss, or has Cisco's algorithm changed in some way? I'm confused as to why one link would work on a 10 year old Cisco 4510 and not a brand new Cisco 9300. When directly connecting the 9300 to the Avaya by patch cable in the closet, the link **does indeed come up**. We only see this problem when using the patch panel to the armored fiber.... which previously worked.

Comment: What type and brand of tranceiver is it?

Comment: What the the types / sizes / classes of fibers involved? Sounds like someone has fired a MM laser into SM fiber, or v.v.

Comment: Can you please give us the reference of previous and new transceivers? Like Ricky said, most chances that you replacer SM opticable by MM  or something like that

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 4):

1. check the transceivers. if their are the same standard?
2. be sure to using LX/LR with singlemode fiber and SX/SR with multimode.
3. the brand of transceivers is supported by 9300?
4. set port to default. (conf t# default interface g1/1/1)